# Como alinhar varias divs com uma única classe

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando recriar esse layout simples:
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvlSh.png)

Mas estou apanhando muito nas divs (quadrado cinza) que tem que estar alinhadas e bem divididas na parte do "portfólio" na foto, mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum.

Abaixo o .html e .css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="teste.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
 <header>
    <h2>Portfólio Desenvolvedor de Website</h2>
 </header>

 <aside id="menu_lateral">
    <div id="foto"></div>
    <h1>Digite aqui seu nome completo</h1>
    <nav>
        <h3>Contato</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>LinjedIn</li> 
            <li>Instagram</li> 
            <li>E-mail</li> 
            <li>Whatsapp</li> 
        </ul>


    </nav>
    <h3>Formação</h3>
    <p class ="destaque-vermelho">Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas</p>
    <p>Centro Universitário Senac</p>
    <p>2019-2023</p>
    <p>Eu to fazendo muita coisa</p>
 </aside>
 <main>
    <section>
        <h3>Experiência Profissional</h3>
        <p class="destaque-vermelho"> Seu ultimo cargo aqui / 2012-2019</p>
        <p>Nome da empresa</p>
        <p>Descrevendo sua função</p>
   </section>
   <section>
    <h3>Portfólio</h3>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
   </section>

 </main>
 <footer>
    <p>Desenvolvido por Lucas - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

.css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



.job {
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: #dd3c3c;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 30% ;
    height: 50px;
    

}

#foto {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 80px ;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
 }

header, footer{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 100px;
    
}

aside {
    padding: 18px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

main {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

.destaque-vermelho{
color: red;

}

nav, ul{ 
   
    text-align: right;
    list-style-type: none;
   line-height: 1.6;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para o que pretendes penso que o mais simples será a utilização de `grid` display. Fiz algumas alterações ao teu código:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.jobs {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 50px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.jobs h3 {
    grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.job {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: #dd3c3c;
}

#foto {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 80px ;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
 }

header, footer{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 100px;
    
}

aside {
    padding: 18px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

main {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

.destaque-vermelho{
color: red;

}

nav, ul{ 
   
    text-align: right;
    list-style-type: none;
   line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="teste.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
 <header>
    <h2>Portfólio Desenvolvedor de Website</h2>
 </header>

 <aside id="menu_lateral">
    <div id="foto"></div>
    <h1>Digite aqui seu nome completo</h1>
    <nav>
        <h3>Contato</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>LinjedIn</li> 
            <li>Instagram</li> 
            <li>E-mail</li> 
            <li>Whatsapp</li> 
        </ul>


    </nav>
    <h3>Formação</h3>
    <p class ="destaque-vermelho">Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas</p>
    <p>Centro Universitário Senac</p>
    <p>2019-2023</p>
    <p>Eu to fazendo muita coisa</p>
 </aside>
 <main>
    <section>
        <h3>Experiência Profissional</h3>
        <p class="destaque-vermelho"> Seu ultimo cargo aqui / 2012-2019</p>
        <p>Nome da empresa</p>
        <p>Descrevendo sua função</p>
   </section>
   <section class="jobs">
    <h3>Portfólio</h3>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
    <div class="job"></div>
   </section>

 </main>
 <footer>
    <p>Desenvolvido por Lucas - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```